# Работа кнопки "Назад" в toolbar в приложении с фрагментами

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-toolbar

Всем здравствуйте!
Пишу свою телефонную книгу. Решил разделить приложение на фрагменты. 
Не получается наладить работу кнопки "назад" в toolbar. Хочу, чтобы по её нажатию можно было возвращаться назад по стеку фрагментов.

В каждом из фрагментов добавил addToBackStack(null). 
При использовании аппаратной кнопки "Назад" всё работает без проблем, если убрать метод onBackPressed().

Код main_activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mainToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        Fragment listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragContainer, listViewFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            fm.popBackStack();
        else
            finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.information:
                Fragment infoFragment = new InfomationFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragContainer, infoFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

метод onBackPressed() сейчас не отрабатывает как нужно. Помогите найти решение, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В onCreate добавить setNavigationOnClickListener у тулбара:

```
mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
mainToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

И убрать свою реализацию onBackPressed. Т.е. вот это надо убрать:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        fm.popBackStack();
    else
        finish();
}
```

Вообще onBackPressed это именно клик на аппаратной кнопке, и у него уже есть обработка по умолчанию, в том числе и раскручивание стека фрагментов.
А вот стрелочка туллбара часто используется для перехода к родительской активности, а не как дублирующая аппаратную кнопку.

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете в одном месте getSupportFragmentManager, а в другом getFragmentManager. Используйте один какой-нибудь